# The use of も; spotting if it is comparison/contrast, or for emphasis

Tags: grammar, particle-も

Could somebody tell me the meaning/use of both もs in bold in the following sentence? It is the background explanation for the essay titled 「さよなら、ゴジラ先生」 in the magazine, [中上級のにほんご](http://www.ssnihongo.com/).

Also, I am not sure about the use of こんな in the second sentence; again what is it referring to? I think it means "this kind of doctor" but what kind? Should I be able to infer the adjective, or is this an invitation to read on and find out?

> 日本の大きな病院は、診察してもらうに**も**時間がかかります。そして、なんだか怖い感じ。でも、こんな先生**も**いるのですね。今月は、大病院の診察室を舞台にしたエッセーです。

The answer must surely relate to context but I should appreciate an explanation from someone who understands.

Comment: @Tim how do you know it means "this kind/good/something doctor" ?

Comment: All; Thank you: 中上級 is correct. (I am not on my normal pc); I have made the mo bold; "this kind/good/something doctor" is just my guess. If it cannot be inferred please say so. T

Comment: We know 先生 means "doctor here because of the hospital context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 日本の大きな病院は、診察してもらうに**も**時間がかかります。

This も means something like "even"; that everything else also takes a lot of time.

> そして、なんだか怖い感じ。でも、こんな先生**も**いるのですね。

This も means "in the world", kind of... I think this sentence is referring not only to the doctors themselves, but also the place where they work, or how they treat their patients.  I guess they want to say something along the lines of: "everyone's so scary; it's hard to believe that there could be doctors who would work in such a place".  However, this is just speculation.  There needs to be more context (i.e., the whole article) to get a good grip on what they mean here...

---

*(See comment to get complete answer to question - Tim)*

---

**Update**

Thinking about it again, maybe it's more like this:

> Even just getting an examination at a big hospital in Japan takes so long.  It can be dreadful.

Comment: Regarding context - I am trying to get help to understand how the title and the by-line to the magazine article are enough in themselves to introduce the article. I agree with you on the use も in both cases and with your help now understand the second sentence is drawing a contrast between the imposing hospital and the "Godzilla-sensei" in the title. They don't tell us what kind of doctor Godzilla-sensei is because they want us to read the article to find out. (Atricle ref added to question)

Comment: Yes, I think it's definitely meant to be a "hook" to get the reader interested :)

Comment: Why the downvote?